# Does the scanpst.exe version have to match the Outlook version?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, repair, pst

Do you know if there are any problems using a `scanpst.exe` from a different (newer) Outlook version with a *.pst from a (older) Outlook?

Example:

If I use the `scanpst.exe` from Outlook 2016 to repair a *.pst used in Outlook 2007, will I have any problems using this repaired *.pst in the older Outlook?

Are newer `scanpst.exe` always compatible with older Outlook versions?

Comment: The only way to know is to try it and see ...

Comment: There are (too) many possible combinations to try...I hope to see some official announcments or already made practical experience.

Comment: I've repaired many `.pst`'s and don't remember Office version causing trouble, so guess it should work just fine. Cannot say about the `.pst` file itself cause it depends how corrupted it is

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this one technical glitch, we should use ScanPST.exe corresponding the version of MS Outlook. Sometimes, bad practices can make the adverse impact on data integrity.

Comment: This implies that you should not use PST created in old Outlook in new Outlook.